# Text-overflow ellipsis in bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

What I want to obtain is a very long textual content in the body of a Bootstrap modal, disposed on a single line and terminating with the ellipsis if longer than the modal width.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <span>Some very very very long text in the modal.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**CSS**

```
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="ellipsis">Some very very very long text in the modal.Some very very very long text in the modal.Some very very very long text in the modal.Some very very very long text in the modal.</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2084/

Comment: Bootstrap 4 answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 4 there is now the `text-truncate` class that will do the same.

```
<h3 class="text-truncate">Name</h3>
```